# Combining many field as JSON and made it into a single field - Performance

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I tried to combine multiple different fields (Stored Fields) into a JSON object 
and added in to lucene document as single field 
I get a better performance while reading the field from the index.
though constructing the JSON requires additional time, It still retrieve the data faster
What is the reason for this ?

I done update reading and indexing the data 
while reading I convert them back to single fields
from JSON object[image: The Test results I done]